# Ubuntu Didn't Gave The Option To Reinstall Without Erasing The Previous Version

Tags: reinstall, reinstalling

I was having some trouble with ubuntu and decided to reinstall it. I was halfway through the reinstallation when ubuntu didn't provided me with the reinstall ubuntu without erasing the previous version(The Red Box In The Image).

[Reinstallation Page Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QvXN.png)

So, what should I do to normally reinstall ubuntu? Otherwise, which is the best option to reinstall ubuntu?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well you should always make a (off-site) backup of your personal files. Regardless. Hardware can always break or get stolen.

And that backup then also serves as a restore option that you can use after re-installing with an erase.

It is up to you what option to pick. One thing though: the "something else"  lets you do it all manually. If you mount your /home and do NOT pick "format" it will keep your /home as is except for the config files. That is basically the option of re-installing while keeping your documents. Again: making a backup first would be advisable.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Any ideas about which option to choose?

Comment: Is that the ACTUAL list you get cuz we do NOT support end of life versions. 17.10 is long gone ;) It is up to you what option to pick: one thing though... the "something else"  lets you do it all manually. If you mount the /home and do NOT pick "format" it will keep your /home as is except for the config files.